# Sliding door menu for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sliding-doors

I'm looking for a sliding effect like this: http://www.piccante.co/sliding-doors/index.htm

But it's for MooTools and I need a jquery version which has a very nice and smooth motion.

Could you suggest such a plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK these are called horizontal accordions.
This is a pretty good library for jQuery:

[Download](http://www.portalzine.de/index?/Horizontal_Accordion--print)

[Demos](http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html) - the designs are not that pretty, but in the examples in the lower sections you can see that you can put any content you want on the handles too.

Or take a look at a more [polished looking one](http://www.madeincima.eu/blog/jquery-plugin-easy-accordion/)

And finally to make it three: [simple & nice](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_simple_horizontal_accordion.htm), ready for your custom styling

I know that 3 is the magic number, but I stumbled across [another one](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/), that is pretty nice too.

Have fun!

Comment: i think the 4th one is better.it has a more smooth motion.